# Automatically link functions/classes in code example in Sphinx documentation

Tags: python-sphinx

I am building code documentation with Sphinx.

Let's say at some point there is documentation for a class `foobar.Foo`, i.e. something like

```
.. autoclass:: foobar.Foo
   :members:
```

At some other place, I have a code example (included using `literalinclude`), which contains the line

```
foo = foobar.Foo()
```

Is there a way to make the `foobar.Foo` in the code example automatically link to the documentation of that class like when using

```
:class:`foobar.Foo`
```

in normal text?

Comment: No. literalinclude does not parse code.

Comment: @StevePiercy Would there be an alternative to `literalinclude` where this is possible?

Comment: could it be that you're looking for [viewcode](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/viewcode.html)?

Comment: @kuropan That is going in the right direction but if I understand the documentation correctly, this generates separate pages for the files?  What I am looking for is a solution where I can embed short code snippets in a page with text around it (like with `literalinclude` or `code-block`).

Comment: @luator Yeah, I'm very much looking for the same thing and am also not yet sure if viewcode is doing that (I read contradictory things about it). We could also take a look at the ``setup.py`` of sklearn, because they seem to have exactly this feature enabled: [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#)

Comment: sklearn uses sphinx-gallery, which can do automatic links

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for? https://sphinx-codeautolink.readthedocs.io/en/latest

Answer (score 0):

The sphinx extension sphinx-gallery can add automatic links to functions/methods/attributes/objects/classes. See https://sphinx-gallery.github.io/stable/configuration.html#link-to-documentation

Comment: Consider adding a summary of the solution in the answer; maybe also include an example. A good answer should contain more than just a link. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231,